# My dataset has 3 tables, and when I want to update a certain table with a web form, it refers to another

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, dataset

This is my code:

```
public partial class AddMovieForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    const string connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Documents\MovieTimeDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataSet ds;
    DataSet genreDS;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = Request.Form["name"];
        string producer = Request.Form["producer"];
        string summary = Request.Form["summary"];
        string genre = Request.Form["genre"];

        int year = int.Parse(Request.Form["year"]);
        int length = int.Parse(Request.Form["length"]);

        string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Movies";

        ds = GetDataSet(sqlStr);

        string genreSqlString = "SELECT * FROM Genres WHERE genre='"+genre1+"'";

        genreDS = GetDataSet(genreSqlString);
        DataRow GenreDR = genreDS.Tables[0].Rows[0];

        int genre2 = (int)GenreDR["id"];

        Insert(name, producer, summary, genre2, year,length);
        Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
    }

    protected void Insert(string name, string producer, string summary, int genre, int year, int length)
    {
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr["name"] = name;
        dr["producer"] = producer;
        dr["summary"] = summary;
        dr["genre"] = genre;
        dr["year"] = year;
        dr["length"] = length;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);

        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
        adapter.Update(ds);
    }

    public DataSet GetDataSet(string strSql)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, conn);

        conn.Open();

        adapter.Fill(ds);

        conn.Close();

        return ds;
    }
```

I have three tables in ds: `Movies`, `Members` and `Category`. Movies is in ds, but when I ran the code, the line `adapter.Update(ds);` causes trouble:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Missing the
>   DataColumn 'id' in the DataTable 'Table' for the SourceColumn 'id'.

The thing is that I have an `id` column only in the table `Category`, and I don't understand why it refers to that table when I filled my ds with the table `Movies`.

Comment: This portion of code `string genreSqlString = "SELECT * FROM Genres WHERE genre='"+genre1+"'";` is extremely dangerous, you're opening yourself up to an SQL injection attack. You're better off using an ORM like Entity Framework, or if that's too bulky try Dapper.

Answer (score 1):

When using a single adapter for multiple tables, between each update you must reset the commandtext and SqlCommandBuilder, otherwise it still refers to the previous one.  For example, adapter was used initially on table1.  To update table2 code is:

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * From table2"
builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
adapter.Update(ds, "table2")
```

Most other posts specify you must use a separate adapter for each table, but I have not found that to be necessary.